# Jquery read items with a specific class, shuffle and display them in the new order,

Tags: jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.slide{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:6;
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function () {
    var countx = $('.slide').length;
    //alert("count " +countx);
    var i;
    var slidearray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < countx; i++) {
        slidearray[i] = i;
    }
    slidearray = shuffle(slidearray);
    var t;
    var pointx;
    for (t = 0; t < slidearray.length; t++) {
        pointx = slidearray[t];
        action(pointx);
    }
});

function action(id) {
    var kex = "#slide" + id;
    //alert(kex);
    if (id == 0) {
        x = 0;
    } else {
        x = id * 3500;
    }
    $(kex).delay(x).fadeIn(1000).delay(2500).fadeOut(1000);
}

function shuffle(array) {
    var m = array.length,
        t, i;
    while (m) {
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
    }
    return array;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id ="slide0" class="slide">Slide 0</div>
<div id ="slide1" class="slide">Slide 1</div>
<div id ="slide2" class="slide">Slide 2</div>
<div id ="slide3" class="slide">Slide 3</div>
<div id ="slide4" class="slide">Slide 4</div>



</body>
```

I am trying to read all div's that have an class of slide on them,  load that into an array, shuffle that array then fade the div's in one at a time in the shuffled order.

it all works great until i try to fade the div's in.  they always fade in 0,1,2,3,4

even thou the shuffle is working correctly,  i cant figure out why they wont fade in shuffled

Comment: What does the line `slidearray[i]=i` accomplish?

Comment: i am using that to load up the array with the correct number of elements that have the slide class on it, i then take that and shuffle it to get a random order

Comment: @jegesh Initialization

Comment: You don't want to shuffle their position on the page, just the order in which they're revealed?

Comment: correct, i just want to shuffle the order they are revealed, I am trying to make a slide show of images that is always in a different order when a user comes to my site.  

it will only show one at a time, and that one will fade out as the next is fading in.

that part all works, it just wont reveal them out of sequence.....

Comment: I'm sort of guessing on this one, but here goes. In the `action` function, you have this line: `var kex = "#slide"+id;`. When you try to call the object `$(kex).etc...` the interpreter receives `$(#slide1)`, NOTE no quotations!  Instead add in `var kex_quot = '"'+kex+'"'` and then `$(kex_quot)`.

Comment: @jegesh i gave that a shot, and jquery actually threw an error on receiving the " around that

Comment: @jegesh You don't include quotes within the selector.  The quotes are what makes it a string, not part of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = id * 2500;
```

`id` here is always the index of the element (**not** the array index) regardless of shuffling.  Therefore, your delay will always be shortest for 0, longer for 1, even longer for 2 etc.  Completely independent of the ordering in the array.  The only difference the ordering of the array is making is the order in which the function is called, which has no bearing on the value of `x`.

Try this instead:

```
function action(id, arrayIndex) {

    var kex = "#slide" + id;
    //alert(kex);

    var x = arrayIndex * 2500;

    $(kex).delay(x).fadeIn(1000).delay(500).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

and call it like this `action(pointx, t);`

http://jsfiddle.net/8jkDh/

Comment: Another alternative would be to base the delay off of a global which is incremented each time the function is called:  http://jsfiddle.net/8jkDh/1/